# SQL query is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is updating views and likes for posts for the last 24 hours, but it is very slow. For around 3000 posts it takes more than 15 seconds to complete, which is a big problem since other queries can't be executed during that period.

```
$update_query = mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE post SET 
                likes_last_day = (SELECT COUNT(post_like_id) FROM post_like WHERE post.post_id = post_like.post_id AND post_like.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)), 
                views_last_day = (SELECT COUNT(post_view_id) FROM post_view WHERE post.post_id = post_view.post_id AND post_view.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY))");
```

Is there a way to optimize this query to execute faster?

Comment: Do you have indexes on any of these columns?

Comment: Run the query in phpMyAdmin and add EXPLAIN at the start (i.e. before UPDATE). Update your question with the output from this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE post p
    SET likes_last_day = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_like l WHERE p.post_id = l.post_id AND l.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)), 
        views_last_day = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_view v WHERE p.post_id = v.post_id AND v.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

You are updating 3000 rows, using subqueries.  That is going to take a bit of time.  To speed the query, you can use indexes:  `post_like(post_id, date)` and `post_view(post_id, date)`.

You could also rewrite the query to do the aggregations before joining the results in.  However, I suspect that the correlated subqueries might actually be faster with the right indexes.

Comment: Thank you. I added indexes and query is executed under a second.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is still an issue after adding indexes, you might think about executing this in a stored procedure, so db would reuse execution plan rather than building it for every ad hoc query.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the amount of time that locks are held on the post table, we can pre-aggregate the results into a temporary table, and then perform the update from that.

As an example:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `__post_last_day_counts__`
;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `__post_last_day_counts__`
( post_id        BIGINT NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk'
, likes_last_day BIGINT NOT NULL
, views_last_day BIGINT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
INSERT INTO `__post_last_day_counts__`
( post_id
, likes_last_day
, views_last_day
)
SELECT p.post_id
     , IFNULL(lc.likes_last_day,0) AS likes_last_day
     , IFNULL(vc.views_last_day,0) AS views_last_day
  FROM post p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT pl.post_id
              , COUNT(pl.post_id) AS likes_last_day
           FROM post_like pl
          WHERE pl.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       ) lc
    ON lc.post_id = p.post_id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT pv.post_id
              , COUNT(pv.post_id) AS views_last_day
           FROM post_view pv
          WHERE pv.date > ('$current_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       ) vc
    ON vc.post_id = p.post_id
;
```

With the counts in the temporary table, we can update post table...

```
UPDATE post t
  JOIN `__post_last_day_counts__` s
    ON s.post_id = t.id
   SET t.likes_last_day = s.likes_last_day
     , t.views_last_day = s.views_last_day
;
```

And cleanup...

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `__post_last_day_counts__`
;
```

Overall this is probably *slower*, but it may minimize the amount of time that the UPDATE statement holds locks.

NOTE: datatype of the `post_id` column in the temporary table should match the datatype of `post_id` in the `post` table.  I just took a guess.

We are assuming that `post_id` is the primary key (or unique key) of post table.

Make sure suitable indexes are available:

```
... on post_view (post_id, date) 
... on post_like (post_id, date)
```

Use EXPLAIN to see execution plan, which operations are being performed and which indexes are being used. (We want to see "Using index for group" in the Extra column.)